# Jenkins build error after slave change

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-maven-plugin

The build for this job is getting failed because of the following error.

I'm not sure what this is about. Can anyone help me resolve this?

[image: console error]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not add links to screenshots in your question but put the original text of your console output in here. :) Further I suggest you look around the (help pages)[https://stackoverflow.com/help] and read about (good questions)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Comment: @danday74 What's your java version?

Answer (score 1):

The first "[ERROR]" line ends with the problem: "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

This means there's a problem with a version of... something. A quick search would reveal that that's the error returned when you're trying to run something (in this case the analysis) with an incompatible version of Java.

The "52.0" at the end could be clearer, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11432195/2662707) decodes that number to Java 8, which is actually the version that's *required* to run analysis, not the version you're *running*.

So. Upgrade your version of Java and/or make sure any copy of Java 8 that's already on the machine is used for analysis.

Comment: Nice. I should tell the folks that want to sell us a similar tool that in order to impress users, they should scan SO for questions, too - so they can give helpful answers quickly ;-)